# .OldValue property in Undo button handler of form gives run-time error 2448

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

This is my first question, so I hope I get it right.

I am working on a project to review Employee information. I am using two forms, the first one is "ReadOnly," the second is "EditOnly."

The "ReadOnly" form is bound to a query, which defines criteria for specific records to be displayed.

The "EditOnly" form has a subform, bound to 2 tables (which are also part of the query that is the source for the "ReadOnly" form), that have a 1-to-many relation (using info from this answer:
[Error 3251 on .oldValue control property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040659/error-3251-on-oldvalue-control-property)).

The "EditOnly" form is opened via a button and is used to edit the data of a specific Employee. In this form I have an <kbd>Undo</kbd> button, using this code:

```
Sub UndoEdits()
  If Me.Dirty Then
    Me!btnUndo.Enabled = True
  Else
    Me!btnUndo.Enabled = False
  End If
End Sub

Sub btnUndo Click()
  Dim ctlC As Control
  For Each ctlC in Me.Controls
    If ctlC.ControlType = acTextBox Then
      ctlC.Value = ctlC.OldValue
    End If
  Next ctlC
End Sub
```

which reverts unwanted changes. But when testing the function, after changing some data I get run-time error 2448. Using Debug highlights this row:

```
ctlC.Value = ctlC.OldValue
```

Is there a way to make the <kbd>Undo</kbd> button work?

Comment: Couldn't you educate users to push _Esc_ once or twice for the same effect?

Comment: That might be an option, but I wanted to try to have an system solution. If is it not reasonably achievable, I digress to this solution.

Comment: Congratulations on your first post! Not too bad for a first question. Actually, compared to most first time posts, I should probably say "absolutely brilliant"! The only thing that stands out is the missing code indentation. It's really important to make sure that your code is properly indented and that you copy-paste the code directly and not type it in manually. The other changes I made were to demonstrate formatting techniques and to correct the grammar. (As English is not your native language these errors are understandable and overall the question was reasonably clear…

Comment: …The third paragraph I couldn't understand fully so I was unable to correct it completely without possibly introducing an error. In my opinion, however, that whole paragraph should have been omitted as it doesn't add any necessary information.) If you haven't already done so, I would suggest reading the [ask] page, after you take the [Tour], so you continue to ask good on-topic questions.

Comment: @robinCTS Hello robin! Thank you for nice review! And please, let me apologize for my late response. I am accesing this account only at work, and its been few really busy days, so I made it now. I will focus more on code and text formatting to make my questions (or someday answers) more readable.
The third paragraph was meant to add information that I thought was usefull (or could rule-out some basic reasons of failure), but maybe that wasnt necessary.
I look at those, thank you!

Comment: Oops, sorry, meant to say the fourth paragraph. However, it looks like we both can't count and *are* talking about the same one, though ;-) Yes, I suppose it is better to add extra unnecessary information, than leave out something important. Assuming it's clear and understandable, of course ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 2448 is "Can't assign a value to this object".

You will get this error if you try to assign a value to any text boxes on the form that are read only/locked or disabled.

Modify your code to check `ctlc` for `Enabled` and `Locked` and skip any controls that aren't assignable, like this:

```
  Dim ctlC As Control

  For Each ctlC in Me.Controls
    If ctlC.ControlType = acTextBox Then
        If ctlC.Enabled And Not ctlC.Locked Then
            ctlC.Value = ctlC.OldValue
        End If
    End If
  Next ctlC
```

**Debugging Tip:**

You can check the value of `ctlc.Name` either by stepping or by writing to the immediate window (`Debug.Print ctlc.Name`) to see which text box is the source of the problem.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Johns response was helpful in some way, but I will actually go with Gustav's comment and try to educate users to use _Esc_.

Comment: Question: Is there a way to make the Undo button work?
Answer: Yes: modify the code so it doesn't blindly assign values to controls without checking to see if the control can accept a value.

Comment: No problem with the edit. I'm not sure I entirely follow the thought that I should avoid giving the impression I'm helping to debug the problem. Isn't that what we do here? I usually try to include a tip about how I would have solved/debugged the problem myself in the spirit of "teach a man to fish..."

Comment: @JohnMo Don't forget to [use @replies](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019) like I've done here so the user you are directing you comment to gets "pinged" (notified). I didn't get pinged by your previous comment - it was only by chance I noticed it, as I *was* pinged by Tomáš' comment on the question. As for the debugging, that is required to be done by the OP. If a reasonably attempt *has* been made, then yes, help can be given **in the comments**. Comments are for asking for clarification (and for minimal debugging help). Answers are for… well answers.

Comment: That being said, if you wish to go further and add debugging tips (which I agree is a good idea), do so *after* you write a complete stand-alone answer, possibly in a separate "debugging tips" addendum. And whatever you do, don't pose the tips in an explicit question/answer style. With the amount of rubbish answers being posted on this site (including full blown questions with code and everything!), as a reviewer, it is way too easy to see an answer asking questions (or just *a* question) and simply hit "Recommend Deletion" without a seconds thought.

Comment: @JohnMo Hello sir, I have been trying to make it work as you suggested, but I might be outclassed here :D
When I try to execute the code, I get:
"Error 91: Object Variable or With block variable not set."

Comment: I tried to find out what this actually means, using this page and MSDN page, but did not found out how to apply solutions from there to my case.
I might be a bit over my head here. I have only basic understanding of VBA and MS Access, I am learning mostly as I go.
I also tried to make work the debug printing in Immediate Window, but I end up with same error, not even able to analyze properties of the textboxes.
Sorry for writing this in 2 comments, I actually couldnt edit the first one after I accidentally added it.

Comment: @TomášKruliš I edited the answer to put in the loop. As the code snippet was, it started trying to use the ctlC without assigning it a value. The For-Next loop is what was providing ctlC a value. This is was the error message was telling you. The object variable is ctlC and it was not being set to anything before trying to examine properties in the IF statement.

Comment: @John Mo Thanks a lot! I think I understand now. Still the problem persists. Seems like code in this form is unable to recognize the .ControlType of ctlC in the form, because the loop stops at Images or Labels (automatic Image, automatic header) with error 438: Object doesn't support property or method.
I already learned a lot, but I must say that I am starting to be inclined to just get on with the _Esc_ button to undo changes :D Because I think I actually understand the code you posted and dont see any point, where could be the problem...

Comment: @TomášKruliš OK, one more edit. The problem is that it's trying to evaluate all of the conditions in the IF statement even if the first condition isn't met. In other languages, we have short-circuits that will jump out of an IF statement after the first condition fails. The way to do that in VBA is to use multiple, nested IFs.

Comment: @John Mo After all the testing I finaly make it work! Also had to skip ID (which is hidden, so I used Visible property). Thanks a lot, the information with Ifs needed to be nested was extremely helpfull.
Have a nice day! Tomáš